# Why are .Net applications slower to start?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Even the most basic application with a simple window takes several seconds to start while its Win32 equivalent loads in a split second.

I read that the delay is not due to the time it takes the JIT to turn the opcode into machine code, but rather the time it takes Windows to load the .Net framework.

So, using MS' [tasklist.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tasklist.mspx) CLI application, I checked if mscoree.dll was already loaded:

```
C:\>tasklist /m mscoree.dll

Image Name                   PID Modules
========================= ====== =====================
explorer.exe                 368 mscoree.dll
BSQLServer.exe               652 mscoree.dll
TOTALCMD.EXE                 408 mscoree.dll
Uedit32.exe                  260 mscoree.dll
OUTLOOK.EXE                 1912 mscoree.dll
```

Next, I ran my basic application with just an OK button, but it still took several seconds to be displayed.

Assuming mscoree.dll is indeed the proof that .Net is loaded, at least to handle basic Windows, then why the delay? FWIW, it's on an XPSP3 host.

Even if the whole .Net framework is loaded for each process, since it's already up and running for other processes, I assume it'll just copy the code from those other processes in RAM?

Thank you.

---

Edit: It seems like slower initial startup time was due to using an antivirus/firewall application, not to the JIT or loading .Net. Another possible issue: If your app is a bit slow to start from a cold state, make sure it only loads the bare minimum at start time.

Comment: How are you running the app, and what kind of app is it? Have you tried a simple console app, run from the command line (just as a minimal test)?

Comment: You could try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what actually happens until you see the application's UI. This would include events like DLL loading, file and/or network access.

Comment: Hard to answer due to the apparently conflicting/incorrect info in the question. Who told you the initial delay is not due to JIT?

Comment: Just check you have compiled the application in release mode

Comment: It's just a window with an OK button and it's the Release binary. I read in several places, including on MS' own site, that the JIT is very fast so slower startup time is mostly due to other factors. Does it mean that a .Net application can start as fast as a Win32 application, even with JIT + loading .Net?

Comment: I ran Process Monitor to watch what that basic application does, and it returned about 2,000 events. I'll check if VB.Net Express provides a profiler to see if something can be done about that.

Comment: FTR mscoree is necessary but not sufficient for loading the .NET framework. It mostly serves as an entry point into the "real" unmanaged portions of the runtime being loaded, which then subsequently load the assemblies like System.Windows. Forms versioned appropriately for the targetted runtime (or runtimes in a process hosting the CLR). With just mscoree loaded you can't even say if this process is gonna be 2.0 or 4.0 (or both) yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple c# test app on windows 7 that starts up instantly, no delay. This is when I doubleclick the executable in explorer. From within VisualStudio it takes seconds because VS then checks if things needs to be compiled, probably does some instrumentation for debugging etc. etc.

Comment: Same here, though I have a pretty beefy machine (SSD, quad-core i7).

Comment: OT: Just installed my 240Gb SSD 6G this month and I most say, Visual Studio loves it :o)

Comment: FWIW, I ran the built Release binary directly, not from VB Express' IDE.

Comment: It might be .NET is doing some security or other stuff, like checking user rights with a domain controller. Not sure, but maybe disable the network for a moment (unplug ;-) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Indeed, slower initial startup time seems to be due to the AV I was using (Comodo, but others problably cause the same issue): Turning it off, waiting a few minutes, and starting a .Net app again shows a slower startup time; Closing and restarting it shortly afterward shows no delay.

Comment: We use kaspersky and it is still instant. You might be able to make some rules in comodo to except certain checks when starting apps. Not sure we did that with kaspersky though.

Answer (score 2):

Avast Antivirus also uses a technique called "Deepscreen" which check excutable files before they are allowed launch. I added an exception for the path to my VB.NET application in Avast Exlusions setting screen and it now starts instantly without any abnormal delay.

Comment: Avast was the clear culprit in my case.  I had a dead simple .NET Windows Forms application that went from 25 to 30 seconds to open each time, with Avast enabled, to then being loaded instantaneously after I set Avast to "Disabled for 10 minutes".

Comment: Webroot was the culprit in my case.  Made the start time for small apps increase from instantly to 6-8 seconds.